# Why does this function crash LispWorks?

Tags: common-lisp, lispworks

When I run this function from a listener in LispWorks, it either crashes the listener or gives an exception and assembly language data. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
(defun should-flip-block (rowlist)
  (declare ((vector number) rowlist))
  (if (= (length rowlist) 0) (eval nil) 
    (let* ((exithigh (= (car (last rowlist)) 2))
           (enterhigh (= (first rowlist) 2)))  
      (and exithigh enterhigh))))
```

It's called as `(should-flip-block '(1 2 1 2 1))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problematic declaration**

Note that not all Common Lisp implementations will think that `(declare ((vector number)) rowvector)` is a valid declaration.

Write instead `(declare (type (vector number) rowvector))`.

**Wrong: a list is not a vector**

The problems you see is because you lied to the implementation and `safety` is set low. You told Lisp that the argument is a vector, but you pass a list (which is not a vector).

The function then use calls to `FIRST` and `LAST`, which don't work on vectors, but lists.

**Run code with higher `safety` value**

Don't run Common Lisp by default with low safety. Use a default safety value of 2 or 3.

Using LispWorks 6.1.1:

```
CL-USER 43 > (proclaim '(optimize (safety 2)))
NIL
```

now I recompile the function and then call it:

```
CL-USER 44 > (should-flip-block '(1 2 1 2 1))

Error: Variable ROWLIST was declared type (VECTOR NUMBER) but is being
       bound to value (1 2 1 2 1)
  1 (abort) Return to level 0.
  2 Return to top loop level 0.
```

Now you see an useful error and not a segment violation.

**Literal Vectors**

`#(1 2 1 2 1)` is a vector.

**Note: `LIST` type has no parameter**

Note that a type `(list number)` does not exist in Common Lisp and can't be defined. The type `list` can't have a parameter. It's also not possible to define such a type based on the type `cons` - recursive types don't work.

Answer (score 2):

You `declare` that `rowlist` is a `vector` (but treat it is a `list` — using `last` and `first`).
This means that the compiler *assumes* that the object you pass to it is a `vector`, so, when you pass it a `list`, you get *undefined behavior*.

The most important thing to know about declarations in Lisp is: *do **not** lie to the compiler*.
I.e., if you violate your declarations (like you just did), you will get burned.

(Additionally, you do not need to `eval` `nil`, and there is no need for the `let*` since you are using the variables it binds just once).

Comment: It's called as (should-flip-block '(1 2 1 2 1)). Removing the declare did fix the problem, but it will not let me (declare ((list number) rowlist)).

Comment: @MarkGreen could you clarify what you mean by "...it will not let me `(declare ((list number) rowlist))`"?

Comment: When I try to use that declare in place of the vector one, I get an error - "don't know what to do with declaration".

Comment: Oh, I think it's a warning. But presumably it's bad since it should be able to do something with the declaration.